# configure Tomcat to support SSL or https

Tags: java, tomcat, https

I am making Tomcat to support https connection.I have gone through this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/) and I configured in my system.It worked fine for me.But when I am trying to repeat the same process(for configuring new system to support https) and entered https://localhost:8443 in the browser in ANOTHER system I am getting "web page not available". Where I was wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to access the first machine from the second one or does this last one have tomcat running on itself?

Comment: @Kappei:NO I am not accessing any machine just configuring in another system..

Comment: Can you post your server.xml file?

Comment: @dash1e:Here is the server.xml [link](http://pastie.org/3797231) same as specified in the link that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: What are the IP of the other system where runs the Tomcat and the IP of the machine from which you try to check the page?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that an Internet proxy is configured on the second machine? On Windows environment, if an Internet proxy is configured, there is a checkbox to check so that local addresses are not to be resolved through the proxy.